# Passing a Delegate to a callback function in unmanaged code using c#

Tags: c#, c++, delegates, marshalling, unmanaged

I have to register a callback function written in unmanaged code from c#. I have written the following codes:

```
//Declaration for c++ code
[DllImport("sdk.dll")]
public static extern void sdkSetDequeueCallback(DequeueCallback cbfunc);
//call back delegate
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void DequeueCallback(OutData data);
GCHandle dequeueCallbackPinHandle;
 Deque = new DequeueCallback(CallBackMethod);
{//try out
// Getting error following line (1 line) , Error : Object contains non-primitive or non-blittable data.
 //dequeueCallbackPinHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(Deque, GCHandleType.Pinned);

 //GC.KeepAlive(Deque);
}
 SetDequeueCallback(Deque);
//Call back method in c#
 public async void CallBackMethod(OutData data)
        {}
```

The above code is working without the tryout block, but the issue is application is getting stopped after a random period of time( some times 30 mins, 1 Hr , 8 hr etc). No error detected in try..catch blocks, but getting following NullReferenceException error from the Windows Event Log(application):
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.NullReferenceException. I think 
[this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-a-delegate-as-a-callback-method)
can be the issue, but tryout codes are not working. Please help me to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to insure your 'Deque' reference is alive and not overwritten as long as the callback is being used in C++. You are responsible for holding delegate C# object alive as long as the corresponding C++ callback is used.

Better yet, just use [Scapix Language Bridge](https://github.com/scapix-com/scapix), it generates C++ to C# bindings (including callbacks), completely automatically. Disclaimer: I am the author of [Scapix Language Bridge](https://github.com/scapix-com/scapix).

Comment: I put the object as static and call the method, now it's working fine.